How to create a dynamic dual-background in a parent view based on a child ScrollView's Y offset in SwiftUI?
I've built a CustomScrollView in SwiftUI that accepts a topContent: View and bottomContent: View, and reports the Y offset along with the frame height of the topContent. Here's my implementation::
struct CustomScrollView<TopContent: View, BottomContent: View>: View {

    private let topContent: () -> TopContent
    private let bottomContent: () -> BottomContent

    @Binding private var offset: CGFloat
    @Binding private var topContentHeight: CGFloat

    init(
        offset: Binding<CGFloat>,
        topContentHeight: Binding<CGFloat>,
        topContent: @escaping () -> TopContent,
        bottomContent: @escaping () -> BottomContent
    ) {
        self._offset = offset
        self._topContentHeight = topContentHeight
        self.topContent = topContent
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                    topContent()
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: geo.size.height)
                            }
                        )

                    bottomContent()
                }

                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: offset)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            offset = value
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { value in
            topContentHeight = value
        }
    }
}

private struct ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

private struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        let next = nextValue()
        value = max(value, next)
    }
}

The goal is to set a dynamic background color in the parent VStack that adjusts based on the ScrollView's Y offset. I want the background in the parent so that all tabs in my `TabView` share the same background. Below is a reproducible example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var topContentHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    CustomScrollView(
                        offset: $offset,
                        topContentHeight: $topContentHeight
                    ) {
                        square
                    } bottomContent: {
                        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                            text
                        }
                        .frame(height: 800)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))

            Text("Footer")
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.red)
        }
        .background(
            VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                Color(.green)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                    .frame(
                        height: max(offset + (topContentHeight), 0),
                        alignment: .top)

                Color(.blue)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
            }
        )
    }

    var square: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 29)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }

    var text: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Text")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

The issue is that the top color (.green) still appears in the top safe area, even though its height is set to 0. I tried to attach a GIF of the issue but it doesn't appear to upload properly.
I've spent hours trying to solve this, but I can't figure it out.

Oh, I just noticed you can swipe horizontally, which wasn't obvious. That explains the paging mode. However, I am still not sure as to what is supposed to change to what color at what moment. So say you swipe left to go to tab 2 (which should say Text 2), then you scroll up. Should the green header background be blue? And if you swipe left and right, what should happen then?

My goal is to have a consistent background across all tabs in the TabView, which is challenging with a dual-colored ScrollView. I can't set the background inside the ScrollView because it causes a 'cutting' effect with the TabView, so the background has to be applied outside.
The issue I'm facing is that the top safe area remains green, even though the green section's height is set to 0. It would be easier to demonstrate if I could upload a GIF, but much easier to see when you try the code out

The problem with the top area remaining green is that you're setting the frame of green frame based on the geo height after ignoring the safe area top edge. Move the ignore after frame and you'll have the main issue, which is the fact that you're not accounting for the height of the top safe area inset, so you'll get a white space.

Hmm alright, but even accounting for the top safe area in the frame calculation, I don't get it to work. Have you managed to get a working solution?

How are you accounting for the safe area? Are you setting a fixed value or calculating it? Also, did you swap the order of the frame and ignore modifiers?

Yes, I swapped the order of the frame and ignore modifiers. To get the safe area, I wrapped the VStack holding the colors in a GeometryReader and added the top safe area as max(offset + topContentHeight + geo.safeAreaInsets.top, 0).

I got it to work @AndreiG. You were right, but instead of adding the .ignoreSafeArea(edges: .top) under the color, I added it under the entire VStack holding both colors

Glad to hear. I actually have been trying to go about it another way, because I find this entire approach too dependent on the sizes of everything. I'll post back if I end up making it work.
